# Why root http requests in netstat - running Ubuntu 12.04 LiveCD?

Tags: 12.04, networking, firefox, live-cd

When using *Ubuntu 12.04 LiveCD* to browse the net with Firefox, I captured the following output using `netstat`:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      root       21355       -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:ipp           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      root       12947       -               
tcp        0      0 10.0.1.103:40710     208.80.154.235:http     ESTABLISHED ubuntu     49343       4190/firefox        
tcp        0      0 10.0.1.103:51222     50.56.4.164:http        TIME_WAIT   root       0           -          
tcp        0      0 10.0.1.103:39295     24.200.237.109:https    ESTABLISHED ubuntu     42454       4190/firefox
tcp        0      0 10.0.1.103:35405     63.251.85.37:http       TIME_WAIT   root       0      
...
```

It seems that root is doing http request? Is it a standard implementation in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and can someone explain a little bit more about it?

Answer (score 0):

Once the app closes the socket, it is no longer associated with that process, but the kernel keeps it around in the TIME_WAIT state for a while to handle any stray packets that may still be bouncing around the Internet and come in later.  Thus, the owner shows up as pid 0, uid 0, which is root.

Comment: This explains why it is never at ESTABLISHED state, so root would not be connecting to the net using http then. Thanks for the clarification.